# Join and scale matrix from TfIdfVectorizer with another matrix in scikit learn

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset composed of some textual and numeric features. Having parsed textual data using scikit's TfidfVectorizer, how do i combine these features with the other numeric features, making sure they're all in the same scale?

The code goes something like this (it's abbreviated):

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as np
trframe = p.read_table(train_file)
traindata = list(np.array(trframe)[:, 2]) #textual
traindata_numfeats = list(np.array(trframe)[:, [4, 16, 17, 20, 22]])
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',
                      analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
                      tokenizer=tokenizer, ngram_range=(1, 1), use_idf=1,
                      smooth_idf=1, sublinear_tf=1)
tfv.fit(traindata)
x_all = tfv.transform(traindata) #how to combine x_all with traindata_numfeats?
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I tried x_all = scipy.sparse.hstack([x_all, traindata_numfeats]) but got this error: TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O')).

Comment: It seems that the other feature matrix has an object dtype instead of an float dtype. Using an object dtype does not make sense in general as to describe scikit-learn model features. Check your feature extraction layer and try to extract float values (that can optionally encode boolean feature with values 0. and 1. when needed).

Comment: I think this might be because some values are missing, eg ['0.9','0.3543','?','0.3343'] - maybe pandas has something that can deal with this? Will look into it. But would hstack be the right way to go? What do you recommend for making sure everything is in the same scale?

Comment: You can replace missing values with the mean or median of a column. check the [Imputer class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html). I would scale your numeric features to unit variance or to the range [0, 1] independently of the text features that typically have wildly different scales. You can optional re-normalizes the rows of the combined features if they are all positive.

Comment: Any further answers to this would really interest me as I am struggling with this. Thanks!